# Disable mouse pressed using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a code to add or subtract from a total amount based on the change in an value of input box. 
It is working when one click happens, but it does't work when mouse pressed event is triggered. The value changes alot but only one unit change occurs in total.

**Edit** Therefore I want to disable mousepressed event on page, so that change always occur one unit

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('button').addClass('btn btn-danger');
        var total=$('#totalspend').val();
        console.log(glo);
        total=parseInt(total);
        $('button').on('click',function(){
            if(glo==-1){    
                total++;
                $('#totalspend').val(total);
            }
            else if(glo==-2){
                total--;
                $('#totalspend').val(total);
            }       
        });
    });
```

Variable "glo" detects the click on increment or decrement button.

```
 <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="totalspend">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
                <tr>
                <td>Striking Speed</td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="35" id="ss"></td>
                </tr>
     </table>
```

Button to increase or decrease are added automatically by plugin 
**https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.nice-number**

Answer (score 0):

Target the div on which you want to disable clicking and then hook it to on click event and return false

Here is the code

```
$('divToDisable').on('click', function(){
  return false;
});
```

Or you can either do this-

```
$('divToDisable').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope it works!

Comment: I ONLY want to disable mousepressed, not click

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: do you know event when mouse is kept pressed on the button?

Comment: I don't think there is any event handler like that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to prevent default event that is being fired when button is clicked, then do your logic. Based on your code it could be done this way:

```
$('button').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (glo == -1) {
        total++;
        $('#totalspend').val(total);
    }
    else if (glo == -2) {
        total--;
        $('#totalspend').val(total);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your issue, I think you need to disable the 'mouseDown' event and run your function on 'click' event.

```
$('divToDisable').on('mousedown', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
}).on('click', function(){
    //your click function goes here
});
```